# $\lim\sup$ vs. $\lim$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

What is the difference between the expressions

$$
\lim\sup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|
$$

specifically with respect to the statement of the Ratio Test outlined in Ross' text?

Comment: The first always exists by definition. The second might not. If the second exists, then both are the same.

Comment: Most important: the first always exists (you have to assume $a_n\neq 0$), the second doesn't.

Comment: The first is stronger because always exists, and in case that the $\lim$ exists is equal to $\limsup$.

Comment: @alex though it may be $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose : $ b_n = \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| $ where $n = 1, 2, \dots $, $(a_n \neq 0)$.

Then $$\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n = \inf_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sup_{k \geq n} b_k\right).$$

While the other one is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$.

Note that (as mentioned in the comments) : while taking inf and supremum, the values $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are allowed to be taken, while in the case of limits it is not.

When limit exists it will coincide with $\lim\sup$, the latter always exists but the former may not.

Check also definition of $\lim\inf$.